# Runtime of algorithem when the internal for depend on the external for

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I'm trying to find the running time of this pseodocose:

```
int x=0,i,j
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=n+r;j=j+i)
       x=x+j;
```

What I did: First I checked  what happened on the first iteration of the external `for`:

- $i=1:$ the internal `for` will run $n+r$ times, so $j\in\{1,2,3,4,\dots,n+r\}$ so $\color{blue}{a_n=n}$
- $i=2: $ the internal `for` will run from $j=1$ to some $k\leqslant n+r$ such that $j\in\{1,3,5,7,\dots,k\}$ so $\color{blue}{a_n=2n-1}$
- $i=3$: the internal `for` will run from $j=1$ to some $k\leqslant n+r$ such that $j\in\{1,4,7,10,\dots,k\}$ so $\color{blue}{a_n=3n-2}$

So the runnig time should be $\color{blue}{\underbrace{n+(2n-1)+(3n-2)+(4n-3)+\dots}_{ n+r \text{ times}}}$

But what should I to now? I should find the running time in $\Theta$ terms, I am trynig to find the runnig time without using any calculator

Comment: The first step would be to correct your calculations. Try writing a program that *computes* the number of times the second loop is run, and compare it to your calculation. The second step would be to sum the resulting series.

Comment: There are plenty of questions about [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops], including our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis). I recommend you look there and find out how to express the costs more rigorously, i.e. get rid of "...". (Nitpick: you are not really analysing "running time". What *is* it you are counting?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1$ the internal loop runs for $n+r$ times, for $i=2$ the internal loop runs for $\lceil (n+r-1)/2 \rceil+1$ times, for $i=3$ the internal loop runs for $\lceil (n+r-1)/3 \rceil+1$ times, and so on till $i=n$ when the internal loop runs for $\lceil (n+r-1)/n \rceil+1$ times.

You now need to sum these numbers. I suggest you read about harmonic series.